# Inapp email stuck in outbox using MFMailCompose

Tags: iphone, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm using the MFMailCompose method to do an inApp email and everything works fine. I sent the app out to have it tested and here is the response from my beta tester.

- My phone is a 3gs 32Gb, OS3.1.3
- Tested at home over wifi, send works with no problems, tested twice.
- Tested again over 3g, send still does not occur until I open my mail box, error still pops up.

Has anyone come across this? His problem seems to be only when trying to send via 3g. It works for me but I'm with a difference carrier. It has to be a settings, but we checked everything. Has anyone come across this?

Comment: I have this problem too, both on WiFi or 3G, and in my apps as well as other apps.  No idea why.

Comment: did you find out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If it works over Wi-Fi and not over 3G, then it's most likely because his device is set to send mail through an outgoing mail server (SMTP server) that restricts connections based on the network you are connected to.

For example, if you have broadband service through FooBarNet, they might tell you to use an outgoing mail server smtp.foobar.net. If you connect to that network while you're at home, the server will allow you to send mail. But if you try to connect to it from another network (e.g., your cellular phone's data network) it will reject the connection, assuming you are trying to hijack its mail server to send spam.

In other words, this has nothing to do with your app. You can verify this by using the Mail app to send mail directly.